# Book: girl on a quest with a group of people; two brothers, one is a wolf; woman gets pregnant by spiders

Tags: story-identification

I read this book about ten years ago. I really want to read it again but I have no clue what it's called. It's a scifi/fantasy adventure about a girl and a couple other people. Two of them are brothers; one of the brothers is a wolf. The girl has some sort of connection with the wolf I think or becomes friends with him. I don't remember much more except for this gruesome part where spiders crawl into some bad lady's belly and she gives birth to a weird monsterfly-thingie. I know it sounds horrible, but i just have to know what book it is. It's been bugging me for way to long.

Comment: 'Bugging'. I see what you did there.

Comment: Although its a very long stretch but it could be the wolves of the calla by Stephen king.